# Nested query inside Logical operator OR not working in meta_query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I've been trying this for hours now and I have searched and haven't gotten a clue. I am trying to make a nested query with `OR` operator as a parent and `AND` operator inside it as child. The page keeps on loading and results are not shown. While on the other hand, if I make `AND` as parent then it works. Here is my code:

```
$compare_array = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'property_size',
            'value'     => '15',
            'type'      => 'numeric',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'property-type',
            'value'     => 'marla',
            'type'      => 'CHAR',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'property_size',
            'value'     => '15',
            'type'      => 'numeric',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'property-type',
            'value'     => 'Kanal',
            'type'      => 'CHAR',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
    )

);

$meta_query[] = $compare_array;
```

Comment: This type of query is going to be very expensive. If you need to find things, you should use taxonomy terms not post meta to do this, it's much more efficient

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm having the same issue, could you enlighten here how can you use taxonomy terms to retrieve meta values?

Comment: @rahilwazir you don't store them as meta, you use taxonomy terms instead. It's much faster to grab posts with the term "red" in the "colours" taxonomy, than it is to grab posts with a meta key of "colour" and a value of "red"

Comment: @TomJNowell taxonomy term meta saves value against term id, right? If so how it's usage will be if I want to save meta values against post id? Sorry, but it doesn't make sense to me. I want to grab each post having custom_rank_{1_2_3} (3 metaboxes) value with `OR` relation

Comment: @rahilwazir no I'm not talking about term meta, I'm talking about taxonomy terms themselves. E.g. looking for posts in the news category is much faster than having a post meta called category that has a value `news`, which is why we use a taxonomy called `category` to organise our posts, and a taxonomy called `tags`, rather than storing that information in post meta

Comment: @TomJNowell Yup, I know that but how can we resolve the OP issue if querying from post meta? I have similar issue, nested meta queries, WP generates too many INNER JOIN and MySQL keep on processing it and never ends. Well I can ask a new question if you think that would be better.

Comment: You convert your data structures from post meta to custom taxonomies and terms. You can improve meta query performance with a table index but they're still slow. What's being done here is slow for fundamental reasons, there's no switch to flip to speed things up. Perhaps a new question would be best

Answer (score 1):

I can see from above query that you are willing to do following thing.

Get all post if `property_size` is `15` AND `property-type` is `marla` OR `Kanal`.

The SQL will be `like %marla% OR like %Kanal%` this is equivalent to `like %marla Kanal%` this will not make much difference (I assume)

So you can minimize this query in this way

```
$compare_array = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'property_size',
        'value'     => '15',
        'type'      => 'numeric',
        'compare'   => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'property-type',
        'value'     => 'marla Kanal',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    )
);
```

In my testing it reduce the query time by `428 ms`

SQL `like` is expensive so if you are matching exact value then use `IN` with array of values.

```
array(
        'key'       => 'property-type',
        'value'     =>  array('marla', 'Kanal'),
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
        'compare'   => 'IN'
    )
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP, but I've different meta fields (keys) on each `relation => 'AND'` array